# Organise imports in Objective-C files

Tags: ios, xcode, code-organization, alphabetical, import

I have some fairly large Objective-C files used in a large scale iOS project. I would like to organise these imports in three ways:

1. I would like libraries to some at the top and individual files to come at the bottom
2. I would like to alphabetise all imports
3. I would like a way of removing unused imports

All three seem like reasonable things to want from an IDE, but it seems Xcode doesn't support any of them. Can anyone recommend any solutions?

Answer (score 1):

I use [Uncrustify](http://uncrustify.sourceforge.net/) to auto-format the sourcecode in my projects. Among other things, it sorts import statements alphabetically. In particular I have:

- created an Uncrustify configuration file using [UniversalIndentGUI](http://universalindent.sourceforge.net/)
- created an Xcode target called "FormatSourcecode" that my main target is depending on and that runs Uncrustify with the aforementioned configuration file

Such a setup will solve your points 1 and 2 since library imports start with "<" and naturally sort next to each other.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve the first two fairly easily by writing a script (in whatever language) that runs on the command line. The third is a little trickier; you might be able to rig something together with clang, but you'll probably have to do it manually.

I agree that it would be nice if Xcode had this kind of functionality built-in.

Answer (score 0):

As the other answer said, you can do this with uncrustify.

```
# sorting imports
mod_sort_import                                     = true
mod_sort_incl_import_prioritize_angle_over_quotes   = true
mod_sort_incl_import_prioritize_filename            = true
mod_sort_include                                    = true
mod_sort_using                                      = true
mod_sort_incl_import_grouping_enabled               = true
```

I'm not sure which of these are needed, but more of them than you think.